# Passing a Pointer Between Functions - memcpy Causing Issues

Tags: c, pointers

I have a struct called `light`, and I create a button event that passes the address of the 'light' struct via the `void *context` parameter;

```
int button_create(const uint8_t gpio_num, button_config_t config, button_callback_fn callback, void* context)
```

When the callback is fired, I can use this struct without issue;

```
void button_callback(button_event_t event, void* context) {
    light_service_t *light = (light_service_t*) context;
    ESP_LOGW("button_callback", "light pointer %p idx %d", light, light->idx);
}
```

But I need to use a function provided by Espressif called `esp_event_post`. This function creates a COPY of the data;

```
        memcpy(event_data_copy, event_data, event_data_size);
#if CONFIG_ESP_EVENT_POST_FROM_ISR
        post.data.ptr = event_data_copy;
```

So when I call this function;

```
void button_callback(button_event_t event, void* context) {
    // esp_event_post sends a pointer to a COPY of the data.        
    esp_event_post(BUTTON_EVENT, event, context, sizeof(void*), 10);
}
```

In the event handler, this line doesn't actually give me back the original pointer address;

```
    } else if (event_base == BUTTON_EVENT) {
        light_service_t *light = (light_service_t*) event_data;
```

So how can I pass the pointer address as.. 'data' (??), and then successfully retrieve the address in the final event callback?

Comment: `esp_event_post(BUTTON_EVENT, event, light, sizeof(light_service_t*), 10);` Why `light` and not `context`? `sizeof(light_service_t*)` is simply `sizeof(a_pointer)`.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct - error with my copy/paste/test. I'll edit.

Comment: Okay, also show how we know that `event_data` is type `light_service_t*`. What we need is [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I know it can be a bit difficult to whittle things down to a short example that exhibits your problem when using a GUI toolkit, but see if you can come up with a short 50 or so line example that can be compiled to validate the issue -- which also provides our ability to use the compiler and debugger to aid in answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this works. Would appreciate any thoughts on this.

First, I save the address as a `uintptr_t`, and then send the address of that;

```
void button_callback(button_event_t event, void* context) {
    // esp_event_post sends a pointer to a COPY of the data.
    uintptr_t shmem = (uintptr_t)context;   
    esp_event_post(BUTTON_EVENT, event, &shmem, sizeof(uintptr_t), 10);
}
```

Then in the receiving event, I convert it back to a pointer;

```
    } else if (event_base == BUTTON_EVENT) {
        uintptr_t shmem = *((uintptr_t*)event_data);
        light_service_t *light = (light_service_t *)shmem;
```

Comment: That looks much more like what I would expect to see. I suspect you can use `void` in that case as well, but `uniptr_t` is fine as well.